# How to fetch previous date data in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I am working on stock project in PHP.Currently while searching according date it is showing data according searching date which is good.But those date which is not avail in database ,it is showing blank,while i need prevous date data.(Like if i enter 25.12.2015,in the result it should show previous date data like 23.12.2015 in this case.)

my html code is:

```
<form action="dateview.php" method="post">
     <table width="60%" border="2" bordercolor="green">
     <tr>
     <td>DATE</td>
     <td>
         <input type="date" name="date">
     </td>
     <td colspan="2">
         <center><input type="submit" value="search"/></center>
     </td>
     </table>   
</form>
```

my php code is:

```
<?php
      if($qw="select * from details where date='$date'"){
      $qq = mysqli_query($con,$qw);
      while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qq,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['itemname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['deposit']; ?></td><td><?php echo $r['withdraw']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['total']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['approvedby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['receivedby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['givenby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['receivedto']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `25.12.2015` or `23.12.2015` is not a valid format, either save the data as a `unix timestamp` or `datetime`. After that, data manipulation queries can happen. Now you would need to [format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) the date before hand.

Comment: change where condition to `where date<='$date'"`. This will give you data of previous date data including the date you passed.

Comment: thanks Code-Monk.Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("23.12.2015")); // o/p: 2015-12-23
```

Where 'Y-m-d' format you stored in DB.

Refer date format [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM details WHERE date <= 'your-date-here' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```