# fetching data according date in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t617g.png)

I am working on stock project.While I am fetching data date wise ,all data is displaying.Like i am searching 23.12.2015  ,it is fetching both records(item in 300 and 200),while i need only last record on particular date like here only second record(item in 200).

my html code is:

```
<form action="dateview.php" method="post">
     <table width="60%" border="2" bordercolor="green">
     <tr>
     <td>DATE</td>
                <td>
                <input type="date" name="date">
                        </td>
                <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="search"/></center></td>
        </table>    
</form>
```

my php code is:

```
<?php
      if($qw="select * from details where date<='$date'"){
      $qq = mysqli_query($con,$qw);
      while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qq,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['itemname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['deposit']; ?></td><td><?php echo $r['withdraw']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['total']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['approvedby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['receivedby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['givenby']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['receivedto']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
```

Comment: `23.12.2015` is not mysql date format. Is your column `date` or `varchar`?

Comment: date format is right and when i am fetching data according date It is showing 2 records which is right because i entered 2 records on that day.But i need only last record.

Comment: Please answer, _what is the datatype of the `Date` column_

Comment: `The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.` -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: @chris85 `input type='date'` does yield a MySQL accepted date format.

Comment: If 2 items have the same date, how do you know which one was added first?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: The table you show does not contain enough information to reliably select the last row entered for any one date. I think you may need to re-think your database design

Comment: didn't you post this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050066/how-to-fetch-previous-date-data-in-php-mysql - Edit: Yes you did and don't repost. Question's closed as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In your code 
    $qw="select * from details where date<='$date'"

Replace with

```
$qw="select * from details where STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') <='$date'"
```

Comment: How this SQL can give the last record?

Comment: you get it from using order by asc or desc and set limit 1

$qw="select * from details where STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') <='$date' ORDER BY  STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: If you see the table there is no field 'id'. This is a incomplete table structure.

Comment: why you need id? without id you can execute query.

Comment: With your previous query you will never get the last inserted value. Because two dates are same as per the image given in the question.

Comment: mohit manu sir this is showing the last entry on the date but i want to find each product's last entry made on that date

Comment: then remove limit and set group by into your query
for e.g. 
$qw="select * from details where STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') <='$date' GROUP BY `product` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC